# Python converting URL JSON response to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

Hi I am making a call to a web service from Python with the following code:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)

df = pd.DataFrame(json_obj)
print(df)
```

The result of this is:

```
                                                               Results
forecast                                          [2.1632421537363355]
index                [{'SaleDate': 1644278400000, 'OfferingGroupId': 0...
prediction_interval         [[-114.9747272420262, 119.30121154949884]]
```

What I am trying to do now is to have data in DataFrame as:

```
Forecast              SaleDate      OfferingGroupId
2.1632421537363355    2022-02-08    0
```

I have tried so many different things that have lost the count.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could first convert the json string to a dictionary (thanks @JonSG):

```
import json
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(string)
```

or use the `json` method of `response`:

```
data = response.json()
```

then use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) where you can directly pass in the record and meta paths of your data to convert the dictionary to a pandas DataFrame object:

```
import pandas as pd
out = pd.json_normalize(data['Results'], record_path = ['index'], meta = ['forecast'])
```

Output:

```
        SaleDate  OfferingGroupId  forecast
0  1644278400000                0  2.163242
```

Comment: @JonSG that's right; missed the part where they said it was a string. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So response coming back from Web service call is of `<class 'http.client.HTTPResponse'>` could you please show an example of moving data from response variable to a dataframe?

Comment: @M.Ali don't you get a json string with `response.read().decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: @JonSG you cannot convert `http.client.HTTPResponse` to json, it throws an error.

Comment: ahh, sorry I missed that you are using `urllib3` rather than `requests`. in that case, import json then line 1.5 should be `data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))` as @enke has demonstrated above.

Comment: @JonSG sorry I think I am missing something, could you please post your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: I'll just make a quick edit to this answer. I think @enke will not mind as I believe it was their intent anyways.

Comment: @JonSG please have a look at my edit I have managed to get the data in a dataframe just not in the format I want it

Comment: @JonSG I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'`

Comment: @M.Ali what version of pandas do you have? Probably should update it.

Comment: current versions of pandas use `pandas.json_normalize()` if you are using an old version of pandas you might try `pandas.io.json.json_normalize()`.